# How convert unicode string from database to utf-string in Go?

Tags: unicode, go

String is stored in database as unicode "\u0435\u043e ..." (table's encoding is UTF-8).

After selecting from database and printing:

log.Println(str)

OUT: \u0435\u043e...

How can I transform this string to utf presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode the string you have, you can do:

```
import "net/url"

...

url.QueryUnescape("\u0435\u043e")
```

But I think there's a misconfiguration of your database or connection parameters, as this should be handled automatically. This is not utf-8 BTW.

Comment: Table: CHARSET=utf8.
Connection string: user:pass@tcp(:3306)/dbtest?charset=utf8.

 Probably database unescapes backslashes and after selecting \u0435 -> \\u0435.